# Creating POI on the routes in SUMO

Tags: openstreetmap, simulator

Is it possible to make POIs on the routes of SUMO automatically?

I want to have the locations of Base stations along the routes that cars or pedestrians move. I have manhattan.net.xml and manhattan.rou.xml as network file and route file in SUMO. I want to create the POI file that has POIs along side the routes with some distance from street. 
Is it possible to create this POI file automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to generate this directly from sumo or the sumo-gui.

If you are willing to write a small python script however, you get a lot of support functions in the tools directory of your sumo installation. There is even a script which does almost what you want: [tools/route/tracegenerator.py](http://sumo.dlr.de/trac.wsgi/browser/trunk/sumo/tools/route/tracegenerator.py%20tools/route/tracegenerator.py). This one generates points along the route. You will have to add the offset and adapt the output format to generate POIs. Maybe write to the mailing list for more help: http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Contact